# GoogleMaps, Marker manager, and Unable to get value of the property '135531'

Tags: google-maps-api-3, undefined, markermanager

I have been working with MarkerManager with a 300 points dataset, and I find that if I set the zoom level of the markers being pushed to the MarkerManager is :
Unable to get value of the property '135531': object is null or undefined

Trying to diagnose the problem I pinpointed the problem to the prototype function: `MarkerManager.prototype.getGridCellCreate_ = function (x, y, z)`

When it goes to assign the grid item: 
`var grid = this.grid_[z];`

it claims that grid is undefined, and the value of z is 135531.

Could some one advise and help to resolve the problem

Comment: Can you provide code to reproduce the problem and/or a jsfiddle that exhibits the problem?

Comment: I take each position from my data
        var posn = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var marker = createMarker(posn, title, td.Details.Iconimg, i);